# Do I need JDK or only JRE?

Tags: java, linux

I use Solr in my website, and now I am about to configure my VPS account.

I am at the stage where I need to install java in order to make Solr work.

Now, I only plan on running solr, and using it as it is (I have no java programming skills at all), so my Q is, do I need the entire JDK which includes JRE, or is JRE enough?

Thanks

BTW: My server OS is Linux (ubuntu 9.10).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the JRE only.  If you do use the admin screens you will however need the JDK as these are servlets.

Comment: To my knowledge, Servlets don't require the JDK... that'd be JSP or JSF.

Comment: From the help article: 

Solr started, and i can POST documents to it, but the admin screen doesn't work
The admin screens are implemented using JSPs which require a JDK (instead of just a JRE) to be compiled on the fly. If you encounter errors trying to load the admin pages, and the stack traces of these errors seem to relate to compilation of JSPs, make sure you have a JDK installed, and make sure it is the instance of java being used. 

NOTE: Some Servlet Containers (like Tomcat5.5 and Jetty6) don't require a JDK for JSPs.

Answer (score 4):

To only make it run `JRE` is sufficient.
However in development environment having a JDK is useful cause with it comes bunch of handy tools for profiling/monitoring the application.
In a production build while packing consider just the JRE.

Answer (score 2):

This [FAQ](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FAQ#Solr_started.2C_and_i_can_POST_documents_to_it.2C_but_the_admin_screen_doesn.27t_work) explains when a JDK is needed instead of just a JRE.

Answer (score 0):

Installing Solr just need JRE which is Java runtime environment, you require JDK if you intend to compile the java programs. Although, installing JDK gives you JRE as well but that is something which is not required by you.

Just install JRE and you will be good to go. For more details on difference between JDK and JRE, use following link:

[Which one to download: JDK or JRE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11037378/which-one-to-download-jdk-or-jre)