# GAE: Cannot get the System Java Compiler. Please use a JDK, not a JRE

Tags: google-app-engine

When trying to deploy my application to the Google App Engine server I get the following error:
Cannot get the System Java Compiler. Please use a JDK, not a JRE.

All solutions I've seen for this involve editing an eclipse configuration file, but I'm not using eclipse.  I'm executing appcfg.cmd from the dos prompt.  I have a jdk installed and my JAVA_HOME is pointing to it:
c:\program files\java\jdk1.6.0_43

Obviously appcfg.cmd is not looking at JAVA_HOME.  It must be getting the JDK location from somewhere else.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you 100% sure you have JDK and not JRE installed (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11037378/which-one-to-download-jdk-or-jre)? If you do have JDK, make sure JAVA_HOME path is set and correct. Open up a cmd prompt and type `set`, a list of environment variables should scroll by, check to see if JAVA_HOME was listed.

Comment: I have both a JRE and a JDK installed, but my JAVA_HOME points to the JDK.  When I run set as you suggested I see this:

Comment: JAVA_HOME=c:\program files\java\jdk1.6.0_43

Comment: JDK is superset of JRE, I don't think you need JRE installed - unless you did so explicitly for some other program. If you need to keep JRE, you can edit your local path to pick up JDK before JRE. I'm not on windows, but try setting PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH% (my syntax may be off).

Comment: I placed %JAVA_HOME%\bin at the beginning of my path as you suggested, and now it is working.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please change that comment to answer. I also switch the 2 Java path to the begining, and it works! Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

As noted in the comments: Make sure the JDK is FIRST in your PATH.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with appengine sdk 1.8.1 and sts 3.6.4.

I tried adding vm properties to sts.ini file, added %JAVA_HOME% to the beginning of the path variable. But nothing was working as I kept getting the same error.

```
Cannot get the System Java Compiler. Please use a JDK, not a JRE
```

Then I found the issue was with Windows\system32\java* file. The appengine was reading the java from Windows\system32. 
There were three files.

```
java.exe
javaw.exe
javaws.exe
```

I replaced these files from JAVA JDK home as they were from JAVA JRE home during installation. After that, I restarted my sts and everything worked fine as I am able to deploy without issue.