# Unable to update app: Cannot get the System Java Compiler. Please use a JDK, not a JRE. GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-apps, google-apps-marketplace

i am trying to upload a GAE java project to google app engine . when i run the command from my command line

```
 sudo ./appcfg.sh update /home/ritesh/MarketPlace/helloworld-java-2011050303/target/exploded
```

it is giving me error logs

```
Beginning interaction for module default...
0% Created staging directory at: '/tmp/appcfg7358649622384760069.tmp'
5% Scanning for jsp files.
8% Compiling jsp files.

Error Details:
Aug 31, 2013 12:55:14 AM org.apache.jasper.JspC processFile
INFO: Built File: /index.jsp
Aug 31, 2013 12:55:14 AM org.apache.jasper.JspC processFile
INFO: Built File: /support.jsp
Aug 31, 2013 12:55:14 AM org.apache.jasper.JspC processFile
INFO: Built File: /WEB-INF/jsp/hello.jsp


java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot get the System Java Compiler. Please use a JDK, not a JRE.
Unable to update app: Cannot get the System Java Compiler. Please use a JDK, not a JRE.
Please see the logs [/tmp/appcfg77694933863265627.log] for further information.
```

can any one please tell how to get rid of this error ??
when i run javac -version it is giving output as

```
javac 1.7.0_11
```

and when i run java -version it is giving me

```
java version "1.7.0_21"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.3.9) (7u21-2.3.9-0ubuntu0.12.10.1)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)
```

can any one please tell how to get rid of this error ??

i am following this tutorial https://developers.google.com/google-apps/marketplace/tutorial_java

PS this appcfg.sh  is in  eclipse/plugin directory

Comment: What do you have installed on the box: `JRE` or `JDK` or both?

Comment: What do you mean by box ??

Comment: We (Google) has released a new experience for the Google Apps Marketplace ([see announcement](http://googleenterprise.blogspot.com/2013/11/third-party-apps-now-easier-to-find-and.html)). We also have new [Developer Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/). The tutorial is no longer up to date or valid.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GAE: Cannot get the System Java Compiler. Please use a JDK, not a JRE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17308139/gae-cannot-get-the-system-java-compiler-please-use-a-jdk-not-a-jre)